# Bootstrap tags input not working with lazyload

Tags: jquery, jquery-lazyload, bootstrap-tags-input

I have a modal that is launched by clicking any one of several images on a page where there is an input field to which I am trying to apply bootstrap-tagsinput.

```
$(document).on("click","a.lazy",function(){        
        $("#form").find(".title").attr('value',$(this).find(".title").val());
        $("#form").find(".title").attr('data-role','tagsinput');
        $("#form").modal("show");
});
```

I am assigning the value and data-role attributes with lazyload to the following input field:

```
<div class="input-group">  
   <span class="input-group-addon">Tags</span>
   <input type="text" class="form-control title" placeholder="Enter Tags for the Image" name="title">
</div>
```

Once I launch the modal I can see that the attributes are present but the tags are not applied. What am I doing wrong?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control title" placeholder="Enter Tags for the Image" name="title" value="yellow" data-role="tagsinput">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding `data-role` is not enough to the input field - because you are adding it dynamically you need to initialise the bootstrap-tags-input like so:

```
$(document).on("click","a.lazy",function(){        
        $("#form").find(".title").attr('value',$(this).find(".title").val());
        $("#form").find(".title").attr('data-role','tagsinput');

        // Destroy all previous bootstrap tags inputs (optional)
        $('input[data-role="tagsinput"]').tagsinput('destroy');
        // Create the bootstrap tag input UI
        $('input[data-role="tagsinput"]').tagsinput('items');

        $("#form").modal("show");
});
```